# Problems with arrays in java

Tags: java

So I'm trying to create a class with an array `a = { 16, 12, 22, 14, 2, 4, 7, 19, 25, 36 };`

The Class should define these public methods:
`public int getElement(int i)`
`Test: Print getElement(5)`

`public void setElement(int i, int newVal)`
`Test: Print toString() before and after test`

`public int getLength()`
`Test: System.out.println(yourclass.getLength())`

`public int[] getValues()`

Return the values as an array NOT an `ArrayList`
`Test: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x.getValues()));`

`public void insertElement(int i, int val).`

`Test: Print toString()` before and after each test

`Test: Print toString()` before and after public String toString()

`Test: produces output similar to Arrays.toString() public boolean isSorted()`

`Test: System.out.println(yourclass.isSorted());`

`public void sort()`

Here is the code. I keep getting error when I put int `a[k] = x[k]`; 
I cannot convert from `int` to an array.

And in line 69: 
`if(a.get(k-1.compareTo(a.length)!=1))`
i got the error cannot invoke `compareto(int)` on a primitive type double

;`enter code here`

```
   package src
    import java.io.*;
    import java.sql.Array;
    import java.util.*;

public class ExpandableArray {

private Array a[] = new Array[10];
private int k;
private boolean sorted;

public ExpandableArray(int x[]) {
    for (k = 0; k < x.length; k++) {
        a[k] = x[k];
    }
}

public int getElement(int i) {
    for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        if (k == i)
            return a[k];
    }
    return 0;
}

public void setElement(int i, int newval) {
    for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        if (k == i) {

            System.out.println("The value at " + i + "is "
                    + a[k].toString());
            a[k] = newval;
            System.out.println("the value at" + i + a[k].toString());
        }
    }
}

public int getLength() {
    return a.length;
}

public Array[] getvalues() {
    return a;
}

public void insertElement(int i, int val){
    try{
        for(k=0;k<i;k++){
            if (k==i)
            {System.out.println("The value before inserting "     +a[k].toString());
        a[k]= val;
        System.out.println("The value after inserting is " + a[k].toString());


            }}}}

void Catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

public String toString() {
    return a;
}

public boolean isSorted(){
    sorted=true;
    for(k=1;k<a.length;k++){
        if(a.get(k-1.compareTo(a.length)!=1)){
        sorted=false;}
        return sorted;}
    }

public void sort() {
    System.out.println("Before sorting: " + a.toString());
    Arrays.sort(a);
    System.out.println("After sorting: " + a.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 16, 12, 22, 14, 2, 4, 7, 19, 25, 36 };
    ExpandableArray arr = new ExpandableArray(a);
    System.out
            .println("Element at specific index is: " + arr.getElement(5));
    arr.setElement(5, 42);
    System.out.println("Length of array is ");
    System.out.print(arr.getLength());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr.getvalues()));
    arr.insertElement(-5, 42);
    arr.insertElement(7, 11);
    System.out.println(arr.toString());
    System.out.println(arr.isSorted());
    arr.sort();
}
```

Comment: it's better in your code snippet to show the line occurring error with comment  like - //error occurred here

Answer (score 2):

> I keep getting error when i put int a[k] = x[k]; cannot convert from int to array

This is because array `a` is of type `Array[]` and array `x` is of type `int[]` (a primitive array) They are nonconvertible. You need to understand the types you are working with and perhaps revisit objects and primitives in Java.

Arrays are created to a fixed size unfortunately and a new array with the larger size is required to replace the old when re-sizing. That is why we use collections such as list and stack. The different implementations of these collections will be doing the same sort of thing as you are trying to achieve.

> in line 69 if(a.get(k-1.compareTo(a.length)!=1)) i got the error cannot invoke compareto(int) on a primitive type double

You cannot invoke methods on primitives as they quite simply don't exist. A primitive is a raw value.

Think of an object as an entity which holds primitives and/or references to other objects (these themselves potentially containing primitives). These are what make up an objects state and the methods that it provides are considered it's behaviors.

It also doesn't look like you require the use of `Array` if all you are creating is an expandable array. You just need to create a wrapper for an `int` array which allows for re-sizing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code:

```
    if(a.get(k-1.compareTo(a.length)!=1)){ // missing ) on the left?
```

make that something like:

```
    if(  a.get(k-1) <= a.length ){
```

Also, don't use `Array`, that's a special class for use with databases. To create an array, just write:

```
 private int[] a = new int[99]; // where 99 is the size you want
```